# @Media print css

Tags: html, css, printing, media

I have my HTML page with this structure:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<nav>
  ....  navigation menu
</nav>
   <div>
         <div></div>
         <div class="to-print">
           <h2>My div to display in print mode<h2>
           <section>
               <article>....content....</article>
           </section>
         </div>
         <div></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      .... HTML elements
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If a user tries to print the page, I want only the content of the DIV with class `to-print` to be printed.  How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7):

If that is the exact structure of your html then this will work for you.

```css
@media print {
  nav, 
  div > div:not(.to-print), 
  div + div:not(.to-print) {
      display: none;
  }
}

/* So you can see the styles working on the elements you want to hide outside of print */
  nav, 
  div > div:not(.to-print), 
  div + div:not(.to-print) {
      color: red;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  ....  navigation menu
</nav>
   <div>
         <div></div>
         <div class="to-print">
           <h2>My div to display in print mode<h2>
           <section>
               <article>....content....</article>
           </section>
         </div>
         <div></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      .... HTML elements
   </div>
```

Comment: if we add an other div as parent of the current first div we will have a problemes, the ideal is to have take all cases with any struct, for examle : if a div have a child with a class to-print the div should be display:normal

Comment: if i want to change the color while print  is this possible ?

Comment: Of course. You need to specify the CSS for the print styles however you wish it to print.

Answer (score 4):

You can you **@media print** and **@media screen** to define what will be printed and what will be shown on screen.

```
 @media print {
       .to-print {
           --css to show content--
       }
 }

 @media screen {
       .to-print {
           --css to not show content--
       }
 }
```

or

Create a new css and include like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/print.css" media="print">
```

Comment: if i want to change the color while print is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media print {
  nav, 
  div > div:not(.to-print), 
  div + div:not(.to-print) {
      color: red ;
  }
}

/* So you can see the styles working on the elements you want to hide outside of print */
  nav, 
  div > div:not(.to-print), 
  div + div:not(.to-print) {
      
      color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  ....  navigation menu
</nav>
   <div>
         <div></div>
         <div class="to-print">
           <h2>My div to display in print mode<h2>
           <section>
               <article>....content....</article>
           </section>
         </div>
         <div></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      .... HTML elements
   </div>
```

See this is not working please correct if any thing wrong.
default color i have make blue
when ever i print the page the nav bar should me red