# How to send hidden information to printer to print

Tags: javascript, php, css, browser, printing

I need to print a Secret(Security) page contain "username" and "password" of user login information with `JavaScript` on the `browser`.

I do not want the contents of this page to be visible for user creator, When user click on Print button, Just i want to send data to printer as hidden, I mean user just see username and password values on `A4` paper and no on the print `preview` on browser.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe you can change preview with javascript in browser. Preview should be exactly the same as final result, so I know what I'm printing.

Comment: and what's the reason to do this? it just make no sense to me.

Comment: Just so you know, hidden elements are still visible in the source of the html page.  The `hidden` value just tells the browser not to render the elements.  They are therefore not very secret.

Comment: @apple-apple I have a admin panel and a admin user that can create user accounts for users, I dont want to admin user see username or password as plain text on print page before print it.

Comment: You can write a css script specifically for printing.  You can create a css class for elements that are hidden and change them so they are not.

Comment: @joseph-j Yeah, I know, But how to send secret data to printer that admin user can not see values, Password is secret and i dont want to admin can see it, Just i want ot can print it and can not see on preview page

Comment: I believe disabling the "Print Preview" would be a browser specific setting, i.e. a CLI flag set to disable print preview.  I've done this for kiosk software I've designed.  There's just no way to do it from JS within a browser due to the nature of the way browsers sandbox your code.

Comment: @joseph-j Of course, But how to hidden element but print it?

Comment: You can make whatever behavior you want - hide, don't hide ect.

Comment: Read this:  Should give you an idea.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699436/media-print-css

Comment: @SajjadDehghani since there exist many virtual printer (pdf printer, image printer...), I don't think it would work in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best you can do in-browser without being able to disable a Print Preview you can achieve it via [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media), the `@media screen` should be hidden, and `@media print` should not.