# How to set div position relative to another div only at printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building an HTML report and I want to move some divs to be above another div @ media print only.
Or, how can I set the position of a div relevant to another one?

example: div_2's bottom to top of div_1 means

```
div_2  
div_1
```

example: div_2's left to right of div_1 means

```
div_1div_2
```

Can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Media print css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699436/media-print-css)

Comment: Unfortunately, no
He is trying to show specific div, not position a div relative to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a very tricky solution which will enable you to change divs at print and also add page breaks if you want. the solution is using Js

```
    jQuery(document).bind("keyup keydown", function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80){
        fd = document.getElementById( '1_div' );
        sd = document.getElementById( '2_div' );
        sd.parentNode.insertBefore( sd, fd );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In many browsers support [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```html
<div class="d0">
   <div class="d1"></div>
   <div class="d2"></div>
</div>
```

EX1:

```css
.d0 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;

}
```

EX2:

```css
.d0 {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: But it doesn't allow pagebreak inside this div, do you know anything about this ?

Comment: try this `.box { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }`

Comment: and read the document carefully https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox